# Grub menu not displaying

Tags: grub, ubuntu-16.04

My grub menu is not showing during startup, as a result of which Windows is loading by default. I have unchecked both hiberante and and fastboot options,
but still default Windows is loading and grub menu is not showing.I tried the UEFI key but it still didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make UEFI bios start GRUB, not Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1247300/how-to-make-uefi-bios-start-grub-not-windows)

Comment: I used the EFI utility which is F10 in HP but couldn't do it.Scott can you please put up the earlier solution that you had put