# Boot from UEFI to Linux

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, efi, initramfs-tools

I have a Windows EFI partition and i have a Linux root partition who contain `/boot/`

---

```
Partition 1 Windows

Partition 2 Windows EFI

Partition 3 Linux Root => /boot/

Partition 4 Linux Home
```

---

I try with `efibootmgr` and `bcfg boot add fs` to add a boot entry to boot into Linux

To do so i tried this command

---

```bsh
efibootmgr --disk /dev/$myHardDrive --part $partition2 --create --label "$linuxName" --loader /vmlinuz-linux --unicode 'root=PARTUUID=$partition3UUID rw initrd=\initramfs-linux.img' --verbose
```

---

And i tried too to do

---

```
bcfg boot add 0 fs1:\vmlinuz-linux "$linuxName"

bcfg boot -opt 0 fs1:\kernel-opts
```

---

. But no fs contain vmlinuz-linux or initramfs-linux.img or kernel-opts. So naturally UEFI say `bcfg: Invalid argument - 'fs1:\vmlinuz-linux'`

---

`bcfg boot dump -v`

---

is way too large to print correctly on the screen to be read

---

`bcfg boot dump`

---

Output :

---

```
Option: 00. Variable: Boot0003
  Desc    - $linuxName
  DevPath - HD(2,GPT,$anUUID,$anHexa,$anHexa2)/\VMLINUZ-LINUX
  Optional- Y
Option: 01. Variable: Boot0000
  Desc    - Windows Boot Manager
  DevPath - HD(2,GPT,$anUUID,$anHexa,$anHexa2)/\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
  Optional- Y
Option: 02. Variable: Boot0001
  Desc    - Hard Drive
  DevPath - BBS(HD,)
  Optional- Y
```

---

And for `efibootmgr -v`

---

```
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager HD(2,GPT,$anUUID,$anHexa,$anHexa2)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{$anUUIDWithDots}...t..............
Boot0003* $linuxName HD(2,GPT,$anUUID,$anHexa,$anHexa2)/File(\VMLINUZ-LINUX)r.o.o.t.=.P.A.R.T.U.U.I.D.=.$partition3UUIDWithDots .r.w. .i.n.i.t.r.d.=.\.i.n.i.t.r.a.m.f.s.-.l.i.n.u.x...i.m.g.
```

---

This question may already have an answer here:

```
How to make UEFI bios start GRUB, not Windows? 5 answers
```

No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how.

---

Not a duplicate, see the second comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make UEFI bios start GRUB, not Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1247300/how-to-make-uefi-bios-start-grub-not-windows)

Comment: Not at all, because GRUB has it's own commands to automatically modify the EFI, but here we have to change it manually

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your boot concept. From what I see, your `/` partition is #4. The `/boot` partition is not ever called the “root” partition. It’s not what you point your kernel’s `root=` parameter at. Are you pointing it at partition 4? Because if you aren’t this is never going to work.

Comment: @DanielB: Sounds like OP didn't have a separate /boot partition at all, i.e. it was just a regular directory within the root partition. (That's common.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded to access to my O.S., it was the "root=PARTUUID" I've used an UUID, so i replaced PARTUUID by UUID and now its okay, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

UEFI can only boot files from partitions which it has a filesystem driver for. (For hopefully obvious reasons.)

Most firmwares only understand FAT filesystems, so your `efibootmgr` entry *must* point to the EFI System Partition (or another FAT partition, but there's no point in having more than one), and you must copy vmlinuz-linux and initramfs-linux.img to that partition.

(The easiest way to do so is to have the Windows EFI partition mounted at /boot.)

Comment: Okay, so I cut all the files from ```/boot/``` and paste it in ```Windows Boot Manager```. After I delete ```/boot/``` and I mount ```Windows Boot Manager``` as ```/boot/```. And that's all, it should work like that ?

Comment: Correction, it don't work. It successfully boot the linux file but it fails to found $partition3UUID so it drop me on emergency shell (```rootfs```)

Comment: (miscellaneous : sh can't access tty; TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errdata; neither fsck nor real root find $partition3UUID)

Comment: Well, that sounds like it worked and you're now having a completely different problem. If you got kernel messages, that means UEFI _did_ start your kernel (and it sounds like it loaded the initramfs as well). Double-check the initramfs itself though; try `initramfs-linux-fallback.img` just in case.