# No longer able to make Linux be the default boot option

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, windows-11, fedora

I have a mini-PC with two SSDs. It came with Windows 11 on one SSD and I added a second one for Linux. I decided to use Fedora with GNOME (I tried to use KDE for a bit because of customisation but it overwhelmed me so I switched to GNOME with some extentions). I managed to set Fedora (or Grub, I guess) as the default boot option through Windows' BCDEdit command (followed [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1247300/how-to-make-uefi-bios-start-grub-not-windows)). But then I started trying to install other distros (pop os and kde neon among them), but then didn't like it and just wiped the SSD and re-install Fedora.

Despite the full SSD wipe some unused EFI entries we're left, and Windows became the default once again. I thought nothing of it, removed the leftovers through `efibootmgr` and then tried the `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\fedora\shimx64.efi` command in Windows again, but for some reason it doesn't work. Windows still boots first, and efibootmgr shows that I now have three bootloaders -- a fedora one with the EFI/fedora/shimx64.efi path, a Windows Boot Manager One and then a third one, with the path set as EFI/fedora/shimx64.efi, but located on the same partition as the Windows one and marked as disabled. It seems to me that the BCEdit command created this third boot entry and even removing it through `efibootmgr` on Linux doesn't help. Is there any way to fix this?

Here are the outputs for `efibootmgr` and `bcdedit` respectively:

```
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0005,0000
Boot0000  fedora  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d0000001f100100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,f02bc1c2-b454-47bc-8bed-a5de3ec0e910,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)0000424f
Boot0005* Fedora  HD(1,GPT,82f2b799-3407-4bbb-9c4d-b13fb8b64271,0x800,0x12c000)/File(\EFI\fedora\shimx64.efi) File(.)
```

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume4
path                    \EFI\fedora\shimx64.efi
description             fedora
locale                  ru-RU
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {95366841-ebcd-11ed-ade4-cf163d6fb670}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 11
locale                  ru-RU
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {367a3f0a-08d7-11ee-bdfb-009337754d14}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {95366841-ebcd-11ed-ade4-cf163d6fb670}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

Comment: When `efibootmgr` doesn't work you'll have to do it manually in the UEFI's Boot menu, as always. As a matter of fact it's where you should have done the first time, not from Windows. And don't forget that when dual-booting with Windows you must disable its Fast Startup "feature".